# how to retrieve data from database using raw SQL not django ORM

Tags: django, database, django-templates

I have a django project that is connected to SQL server database and when i tried  to click button to  retrieve data from the database the system crash .

i am trying to convert the below syntax in ORM  into  raw sql:

```
dbEntry = Person_.objects.get(pk =pk)
```

Note : **I am not using ORM**

once i tried to perform the task the system crash and display:

> getEvents() got unexpected keyword argument "id"

## urls.py

```
path("events/<int:id>/",getEvents,name = "getEvents"),
```

## views.py

```
def getEvents(request,pid):
  q1 = cuesor.execute("Select Person_.ID FROM Person_ WHERE ID = pid")
  print("q1=",q1)
  qresult = q1.fetchone()
  print("qresult",qresult)
  return render(request,"connect.html",{"qresult":qresult})
```

## list.html

```
<form method = "GET" action = "{% url 'getEvents' obj.0 %}"# obj is the iterator --- 0 is the first field in the table == ID
   <button class = "btn btn-primary">get details</button>
</form>
```

## display.html

```
{% for row in qresult %}
  <p> {{ row.0 }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because in your urls.py, you have declared the path as:

```py
"events/<int:id>/"
```

Your url parameter is named **id** and that is what your view will receive as an argument, not **pid**.

Also I noticed that your SQL command might be wrong, you are not adding the actual value of **pid** to the string.
I think you want it to be like this:

```py
"Select Person_.ID FROM Person_ WHERE ID = {0}".format(id).
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to DB, in your urls, you have defined 
`path("events/<int:id>/",getEvents,name = "getEvents"),`, here the argument name is `id`.

You need to provide the same name to you argument in your function arguments. Change this

```
def getEvents(request,pid):
```

to

```
def getEvents(request,id):
```